# Calling a function

Tags: c++, function, call

Pardon me, this must be one of the silliest questions ever asked especially since I've already called one function. I have called one function with one return value and set that return value equal to a variable but with another function that returns 2 variables; I just want to run the function and return the values.

my declaration:

```
string diagraph ( string mono1, string mono2);
```

calling the function:

```
cout << diagraph (mono1,mono2);
```

The function itself:

```
string diagraph(string mono1, string mono2) {
    string encoded1,encoded2;
    int a,b,c,d,e,f;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    while( mono1 != cipherarray[b][c]){
        b++;
        if (b == 5) {
            a = 0;
            b++;
        }
    }
    a = c;
    b = d;


    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    while (mono2 != cipherarray[b][c]){ 
        b++;
        if (b == 5) {
            a = 0;
            b++;
        }
    }

    a = e;
    b = f;
}
```

The errors(having to do with calling the function):

```
C++\expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<<' token 
 expected `,' or `;' before '<<' token
```

the function is not finished but it will return 2 strings

Comment: I am not finished but it should return encode1,encoded 2. I see your point but it didnot give me an error for not finishing the function,only for calling it.

Comment: C++ doesn't have multiple-return-value support, if that's what you're asking. You can't do return (a, b) and expect to get anything useful. (Ignoring the behavior of the possibly-overloaded comma operator, of course.)

Comment: @user: You at least need to stub the function with a return statement at the end, not having a return statement gives you undefined behavior. In any case, you need to show us the full source listing.

Comment: Looking at the error message, I think the compiler doesn't know what 'cout' or '<<' is. Check your includes.

Comment: Show a more complete example. How do you include the headers declaring cout? Are you properly "using" std?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I don't see a single return statement in that function.  Second, you can't return two values from a function.  You can either return a single string (as your function definition says it will) or you can modify passed in values (as long as they are references or pointers).

EDIT:  To elaborate

If you want to modify passed in values they will need to be references or pointers.  This is because the default behavior in C++ is to pass arguments by value (copy), so any change to the functions parameters will not be visible from outside of the function.  However, if the arguments are references/pointers you can mutate what they already point to (or pointers to pointers if you want to change what the original pointer points to, i.e., not a mutation, but an assignment to a new value/object).

Comment: AHH... pointers drive me crazy! they seem to be pointless but they worm their way into every subject in C++.

Comment: Pointers are hardly pointless.  How would you suggest implementing any program without pointers? At some level pointers are used everywhere.  Anyways, you can (should) just take a reference in that case anyway.

Comment: In my books it says pointers point to a value in memory but it always seems to me, pardon my ignoranc that you can just use variable names

Comment: I kind of see what your saying, so I can store the strings in memory then use pointers to access them? could you give me an example?

Comment: They are not the same thing.  A variable name in C++ is simply an identifier and only a pointer if it is declared as such.  A pointer is an address that can be dereferenced in order to access (usually) dynamically allocated memory.  A variable declared in the fashion of SomeType x; is allocated on the stack and the semantics are very different.  There is more to it than what I have just generalized here, you really need to study the differences between the two if you want to write code in C++.

Comment: sorry I had yet to see grammins post; I,m so popular :)

Comment: I am a bitimpatient when it comes to learning, I will look into it though

Comment: Well, good luck with that.  You aren't going to learn anything non-trivial if you're impatient.

Comment: @user: You are somewhat right. I (almost) never use pointers in my C++ programs and it works out just fine for me. Granted, pointers are used *under the hood* by the classes that I in turn use. But the point is that I don’t have to care about the pointers, and neither should you. And with all due respect, Ed did you a disservice by recommending pointers here. Either use references or (better, in my opinion) return a `pair` of strings, or a `vector` of strings.

Comment: "More information has been produced in the past 30 years then in the past 5000 combined"

Comment: Meaning I'm going to look into pointers, vectors, references, pairs, life was simplier in neolithic times

Comment: @Konrad: I did suggest the use of references over pointers, and the whole point was to explain why you need to use either to modify an argument to a function.  Also, you may not need to use pointers often, and I agree that they should be avoided in most C++ code, but we don't all have the luxury of avoiding pointers altogether.  I work in systems and the API's/device drivers that I call into utlize pointers heavily.  You can't just ignore them as if they don't exist.

Comment: Ok, actually, after re-reading my response I didn't actually advocate the use of references over pointers (though I meant to).  user: use references over pointers whenever possible.

Comment: I hope you guys are not getting bored of this. in this case should i use std:pair or references

Comment: Nah, not bored; I'm just writing a performance evaluation at work after all :D

Comment: If you guys are still there I have decided to use the pair the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

Check the line of code *above* `cout << diagraph (mono1,mono2);` to make sure you haven't missed a trailing semicolon, or left a parenthesis open.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to compile and run your code only gives me a warning about end of a non-void statement.

I recommend at least adding a placeholder return value until the function is done, something like `return "";`.

Comment: itsnice you would do so for a stranger

Comment: Gotta get that rep! :)  Glad to help.

Comment: I put that in, how can I return two values?

Comment: Cannot be done, not in C or C++.  You could return a `std::pair` of strings, which is a single object that contains two strings.

Comment: If you want the function to return two values, either pass them as reference or use std::pair to return them if you will be having only 2 return values.

Comment: thank you, everyones giving me a different answer, its alot to take in

Answer (score 0):

It appear that does not like the 'cout', are you including the namespace std?
Also, check that you declare the function before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The full code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;
string getletter(string f = "q", string g = "q", string h = "q", string i = "q", string j = "q", string k = "q", string l = "q" ); 
 string diagraph ( string mono1, string mono2);



char type[81];
char filename[20];
char key [20];
string f = "q";
string g = "q";
string h = "q";
string i = "q";
string j = "q";
string k = "q";
string l = "q";
string mono1; 
string mono2;

int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int e = 0;
int m = 0;

string cipherarray[5][5]= {
{"a","f","k","p","v"},
{"b","g","l","r","w"},
{"c","h","m","s","x"},
{"d","i","n","t","y"},
{"e","j","o","u","z"}

};
int main(){









cout<<"Enter the name of a file you want to create.\n";

cin>>filename;

cout<<"enter your codeword(codeword can have no repeating letters)\n"; 

cin>>key;

while (key[a] != '\0' ){

while(b <= 4){
        m++;
cipherarray[b][c] = key[a];

 if (m == 1 ) {
f = cipherarray[b][c];
}

 if ( m == 2 ) {
g = cipherarray[b][c];
}

 if ( m == 3 )
 {
h = cipherarray[b][c];
}

 if ( m == 4  )
 {
i = cipherarray[b][c];
}


 if ( m == 5 ) 
{
j = cipherarray[b][c];
}

 if ( m == 6 )
 {
k = cipherarray[b][c];
}

 if ( m == 7 )
 {
l = cipherarray[b][c];
}


a++;
b++;
if (key[a] == 0)
break; 
}

if (key[a] != 0){
c++;
b = 0;
}
}


// code to copy alphabet from getletter function onto cipherarray array
while ( c <= 4) {
while ( b <= 4) {
 cipherarray[b][c] = getletter(f,g,h,i,j,k,l);
 b++;     
}
b = 0;
c++;
} 









// code to display cipher array onscreen

b = 0;
c = 0;
cout<<endl<<endl<<"                      ";

string getletter(string f, string g , string h  , string i  , string j , string k , string l ) {
string letter;
string cipherarraytemplate[5][5]= {
{"a","f","k","p","v"},
{"b","g","l","r","w"},
{"c","h","m","s","x"},
{"d","i","n","t","y"},
{"e","j","o","u","z"}
};





while (cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == f || cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == g || cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == h || cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == i ||
 cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == j || cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == k || cipherarraytemplate[d][e] == l){ 
 d++; 
 if (d == 5){
e++;
d = 0;
}
 } 


letter = cipherarraytemplate[d][e];

d++;
if (d == 5){
e++;
d = 0;
}
return letter;
}

string diagraph(string mono1, string mono2) {
string encoded1,encoded2;
int a,b,c,d,e,f;
a = 0;
b = 0;
while( mono1 != cipherarray[b][c]){
b++;
if (b == 5) {
a = 0;
b++;
}
}
a = c;
b = d;


a = 0;
b = 0;

while (mono2 != cipherarray[b][c]){ 
b++;
if (b == 5) {
a = 0;
b++;
}
}

a = e;
b = f;
return "";
}
```